# Can I delete ios folder in Flutter Project and recreate it?

Tags: flutter

I have an application successfully running on Android and now I'm trying to run it on iOS. However, I'm getting a lot of build errors because I wanted to migrate from Swift 4 to Swift 5.

Can I just delete the whole iOS folder and recreate it using Swift 5 so I don't have to manually update the failures?

Answer (score 3):

Yup, you can try this to recreate the ios folder

```
flutter create -i swift
```

if this doesn't works let me know

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in project terminal ->

```
flutter create .
```

This will recreate all the necessary folder and files needed to run the project.